# how do i fix 400 (Bad Request) error about admin-ajax.php

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I want to deliver html value through JS to PHP handling, but I still got error, 400 (Bad Request) .

This is HTML:

```
</div>
            <form class="row g-3" id="my_form">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <label for="url" class="form-label">Input URL</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control my_info" id="url" required>
        
              <div class="col-12">
                <button class="btn btn-primary submit" type="button">Submit form</button>
              </div>
            </form>
   </div>
```

This is JavaScript:

```
function getBaseUrl() {
    var re = new RegExp(/^.*\//);
    var my_local_url = re.exec(window.location.href)[0];

    return my_local_url;
}

console.log(getBaseUrl())

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    console.log('test');
    // We'll pass this variable to the PHP function example_ajax_request
    var my_data = {
        'action':'crawler_info',
        'my_info' : document.getElementById('url').value
    };
    $('.submit').click(function (){
        // This does the ajax request
        $.ajax({
            url: getBaseUrl() + 'admin-ajax.php',
            data: my_data,,
            success:function(data) {
                // This outputs the result of the ajax request
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(errorThrown){
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        }); 
    })
});
```

This is PHP:

```
function get_info() {

    // The $_REQUEST contains all the data sent via ajax 
    if ( isset($_REQUEST) ) {

        $infos = $_REQUEST['my_info'];

        // Now we'll return it to the javascript function
        // Anything outputted will be returned in the response
        echo $infos;

        // If you're debugging, it might be useful to see what was sent in the $_REQUEST
        print_r($_REQUEST);

    }

    // Always die in functions echoing ajax content or it will display 0 or another word
   die();
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_crawler_info', 'get_info' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_crawler_info', 'get_info' );
```

I have try many way to fix it, but it still display this error again.
Does anybody know how to solve my problem,Thanks

Comment: Maybe you could try calling your .php from some tool as postman or insomnia and verify if works as you expected. Then, try again from html+js

Comment: @Mate thanks for your answer, these tool are not work based on wordpress and not use its hook, so these tool can't solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed my problem, some code put in wrong place I found

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).